# Pickup NuGet package version from the packed assembly version

Tags: build, nuget

How can I make a version of a NuGet package set automatically the same as the packed assemblie's version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [replacement tokens in the .nuspec file](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package) if you use `nuget pack YourProject.csproj`.

If you run `nuget spec` in the same directory as your project file (.csproj) you will have a .nuspec file generated with the replacement tokens already defined. The version replacement token in the .nuspec file, as shown below, will tell NuGet to use the assembly version:

```
<version>$version$</version>
```

Then you can run `nuget pack YourProject.csproj` to generate the NuGet package.

If you cannot use `nuget pack YourProject.csproj` then you would need to write a utility to read the assembly version and then populate the .nuspec file with the version, and then run `nuget pack YourNuSpec.nuspec`.